# How to use jQuery on a control in Google Maps API

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps

I'm trying to use jQuery on a control in the Google API v3.  Like this:

```
var button = document.createElement("button");

button.id = "control-test"
button.index = 2;
button.innerHTML = "Test!";
button.style.padding = "5px";
button.type = "button";

map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(button);
```

The button is created but none of the jQuery I throw at it are applied:

```
$("#control-test").button().click(function () {

    alert("CLICK!");

});
```

I'm thinking maybe it has something to do with the DOM availability.  Should it be possible to do something like this and how?

Comment: At which point are you running the jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to delegate event, e.g:

```
$(document.body).on('click',"#control-test",function () {

    alert("CLICK!");

});
```

Comment: Now this works! Can it be written to work with jQuery UI's .button()?

Comment: I don't  know what returns jquery UI button. I suppose if you set it as: $("#control-test").button(); the delegated event will still work. You need to test it.